# Standing water in gutters

Tags: shed, gutters, downspout

I have a 1 car garage shed with gutters around the roof. There are two downspouts, both on the same side of the structure (there is an alley on one side so both drain into the alley). I was up on the roof with a hose trying to find a roof leak when I noticed that the water was just accumulating (probably 3/4" or so) in the gutters but not flowing to the back of the shed to the downspouts.

Is this ok/normal? Presumably with enough water it would make its way back to the downspouts? Is it possible to increase the pitch of the side gutters so that the water flows toward the back even with a little bit of water in the gutter?

------EDIT------

The gutter seem to be sensibly straight/in good shape. The standing water is in the gutter shown, and the downspouts are on the side of the shed to the right of this picture:
[image: gutter straightness]

Here is the water:
[image]

Can I bend the brackets near the opposite corner a bit to make the gutter slope toward the downspouts?

Comment: Are the gutters sagging in the middle? That seems like a lot of water to be sitting there.

Comment: @JACK I added some pictures to the post.

Comment: The gutter is not sloped properly towards the down spout or the down spout is blocked some how

Comment: Is the water level the same across the entire front of the shed? If so, you'll have to re slope the gutter on the side of the spout.

Comment: @Kris the water is not even reaching the downspouts, so they aren't the culprit :)

Comment: @JACK Yea... now I just have to figure out how to do that! I moved one of the brackets up and that didn't seem to put a dent in it - I guess I have to take all of the brackets off, adjust the gutter, then put them all back on? Yikes... And it's worse because the side of the shed opposite the downspouts is also flat, so I have to try to slope it down from the center, THEN the side in the picture down further back to the side with the downspouts...

Comment: Are there 4 downspouts? One per corner?

Comment: @Kris nope, just two on the same side (not the corners) - the side tot the right of the side shown in the picture.

Comment: That’s unusual.  it’s hard to keep a slope going so far. Generally there would be 4 drops with each side of the building being sloped to the right and left from center.

Comment: I think it's safe to close this one with "The gutters are improperly pitched". Someone want to add that answer so I can accept it :) ? I do have more questions about pitching gutters, but I'll start a new Question for that.

Comment: Here it is: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171079/gutter-pitch-configuration