# Peeling on bottom of gutter

Tags: gutters

My gutter is leaking at the corner. After some youtubing, it seems like I'd want to just re-seal the miter (essentially just caulk). However, mine seems to have a rubber-like substance along the whole bottom of the inside of the gutter (the red arrow in the picture points to the edge of the peeling material). I didn't see this in any of the gutter installation videos I watched - what is it called? Can I just pull this up (it's really stuck on there) so I can re-caulk the seam? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like somebody already tried to seal it in the past. You can pull, scrape the stuff off and re-caulk the seam. Just be careful not to dig a hole in the cutter, they are pretty soft.

Comment: agree, also you will need to spend some time removing **all** the suspect sealant and make sure the surface is *clean* and *dry*, or the new caulk will not bond and seal properly...

Comment: Good point Jimmy.

Comment: Sounds like a plan - now I just have to wait for the water to dry up so I can try it :) https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170947/standing-water-in-gutters